# Update database row by id fails

Tags: kotlin, android-sqlite

I'm trying to update a specific row by ID :

```
fun updateEmployeeInfo(id:Int, firstName:String): Int {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    var cv = ContentValues()

    cv.put(COL_FIRSTNAME, firstName )
    val result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, COL_FIRSTNAME+"=?", arrayOf(firstName))
    return result
}
```

Running this with an ID that already exists in the database it isn't updating.

[screenshot of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QML0n.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are saying update the rows with the provided (passed) first name by changing the first name to the very same first name (effectively doing nothing).

I believe that you want to use:-

```
val result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, COL_ID+"=?", arrayOf(id.toString))
```

- assuming that COL_ID holds the value of the id column name.
- or you could use the more concise `return db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, COL_ID+"=?", arrayOf(id.toString))`

This is then saying update the row where the id is the provided/passed id changing the first name, whatever it is, to the provided/passed first name.